# An iterative sequence of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, several-complex-variables

Consider a disk at center at $(0,0)$ of radius, $r$ $B_r(0)$ in the complex plane. Let $w_1$ and $w_2$ be two complex numbers belong to the disk $B_r(0)$. Consider a scheme,

$$w_k=\frac{a}{w_{k-1}}+\frac{b}{w_{k-2}}$$ $k=1,2,3,\dots,$

How can we determine the radius $R$ of the disk $B_R(0)$ such that $w_k \in B_R(0)$ for all k?

Comment: Your title is very misleading. Perhaps you could use "An iterative sequence of complex numbers" or such?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have edited.

Comment: There's no reason why you shouldn't have $w_k = 0$ for some $k$, which results in (assuming $a\neq 0 \neq b$) $w_{k+1} = \infty,\, w_{k+2} = \infty,\, w_{k+3} = 0,\, w_{k+4} = \infty,\,\dotsc$, or $w_k$ coming arbitrarily close to $0$, which can produce an unbounded sequence of complex numbers. In short, there is no reason to assume such an $R$ exists at all.

Comment: You are correct, Daniel. Could you please help me to find out list of initial values for which $w_k=0$ for some $k$?